# C++ STL Interleave two ranges

Tags: c++, stl

I did something to achieve interleaving two ranges. Here is the problem.

Say I have two ranges `[a1, b1), call R1` and `[a2, b2) call R2`. For now, assume their `std::distance` results are the same, say `n`. I want to write an algorithm

`std::interleave(a1, b1, a2, b2, bool swap)`

This will reorder the elements in a way that one element of R2 will be followed an element of R1, through all `2n` elements. Depending of the value of `swap`, it should also be reordered as one element of R1 is followed by an element of R2.

I did this using an additional storage and two for loops. This solution is easy. I could also come up with an in-place solution probably, if I tried a little longer. But what I want is, I want to achieve this thing by assembling algorithms from the STL. How can you solve this problem using STL? It is better if the solution is in-place but I am also open to usage of additional storage, as long as we use algorithms from the STL.

EDIT: The permutation of the elements in the given ranges should not be changed. In other words, this should actually be something like `stable_interleave`. This is why I couldn't come up with something that uses `std::merge`.

APPLICATION: One application of this is the conversion of video and image formats from planar to non-planar or semi-planar.

Comment: You might be able to beat [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) into doing most of the heavy lifting for you. Unrelated: Don't put stuff into the `std` namespace. There are only a few times you're allowed to and this isn't one of them.

Comment: I just wrote `std::` to indicate that I am looking for a solution in the style of STL. About `std::merge`, I thought about it but my ranges are not sorted and their specific permutation kept unchanged is a requirement for me.

Comment: You can supply a comparator that returns  true, false, true, false....

Comment: Example: https://ideone.com/6XnYWC

Comment: I was not able to think of this alternating comparator idea, this is great. If you want to, you can write it as an answer and I can accept.

Comment: boost have [zip iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pitch of using `std::merge` can fail. I'm not creative enough to see why anyone would write `merge` so that it could, but it is violating the requirements for [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) as pointed out in the comments below, so someone could.

Regardless, `merge` is an overkill solution. It is fewer lines of code hiding extra effort because `merge`'s intended usage is for a more complicated job than we do here.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>

template<typename IN1,
         typename IN2,
         typename OUT>
inline OUT interleave(IN1 it1,
                      IN1 end1,
                      IN2 it2,
                      IN2 end2,
                      OUT out)
{
    // interleave until at least one container is done
    while (it1 != end1 && it2 != end2) 
    {
        // insert from container 1
        *out = *it1;
        out++;
        it1++;
        // insert from container 2
        *out = *it2;
        out++;
        it2++;
    }
    if (it1 != end1) // check and finish container 1
    {
        return std::copy (it1, end1, out);
    }
    else if (it2 != end2)// check and finish container 2
    {
        return std::copy (it2, end2, out);
    }
    return out; // both done
}

int main()
{
    // fill the containers  with numbers
    std::vector<int> in1 = {1,3,5,7,9};
    std::list<int> in2 = {8,6,4,2};

    // construct output container of sufficient size.
    // Could also use empty container and *_inserter
    std::deque<int> out(in1.size() + in2.size());

    // Container-agnostic. reads from vector and list and stores in deque
    interleave(in1.begin(), in1.end(),
               in2.begin(), in2.end(),
               out.begin());
    for (int val: out)
    {
        std::cout << val << ' ';
    }
}
```

Note: rather than implementing with an option to swap the order of the inputs and making all users of `interleave` pay for it, the caller should call with the order of input parameters reversed.